# npm probleme to start project

Tags: npm, jhipster

when i do npm install i have this error in debian :
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! generator-jhipster@4.14.5 postinstall: `opencollective postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the generator-jhipster@4.14.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/esp/.npm/_logs/2020-09-10T17_16_09_060Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

1. Delete node modules `del node modules`
2. then  del package-lock.json
3. Now jus run again `npm i`

still not working then run `npm cache clean --force`
After Completion then you can run `npm install` and make sure that you are in admin mode.

like Run your project / Terminal as a Admin Mode
In Linux you can use `sudo` / sudo npm insatll